# How to set the footer of Windows notification balloon?

Tags: c#, .net, notifyicon

I have the following code that displays the Notification balloon of the NotifyIcon class:

```
var appSysTray = new NotifyIcon();
appSysTray.BalloonTipTitle = "Eye of Sauron";
appSysTray.BalloonTipText = "Unable to connect to the ...";
appSysTray.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

And the notification is displayed.  One thing that I can't seem to control is the footer of the notification.  How do I set that?  Right now it seems to be the name of the assembly.

[image]

Comment: Is EyeOfSauron your program name?

Comment: @FrankerZ for this example, yes.

Comment: Well then, that's what's being set as your footer text. Change the name of the program, change the footer text.

Comment: To add a little more detail to what @FrankerZ said, that's done in the Project properties window

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks.  That did it.  Specifically, Project Properties/Application/Assembly Information/Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer of the notification title, is related to the title of your program (Project Properties => Application => Assembly Information => Title). You can find this in the project properties window:

[image]