# In Windows 10, how do I translate the footer of a tray notification balloon?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Regarding this question: [How to set the footer of Windows notification balloon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525635/how-to-set-the-footer-of-windows-notification-balloon) - how do I deal with translating the footer of a tray notification balloon? I have a multilingual application that will have a single .exe file. What I would like to achieve is that the footer is translated to appropriate language (calculated by the application itself, based on multiple factors). So how do I programatically set the footer to an arbitrary text?

If that's not possible, is it possible to just hide the footer completely?

Comment: @rustyx I know that it boils down to RC file manipulation. Unfortunately the link you posted does not answer the question about how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Using the Qt's [System Tray Icon Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html) as a starting point...

You need to add to the project a `systray.rc` file, and declare it in the Qmake project file (`systray.pro`) like this:

```
RC_FILE       = systray.rc
```

That line will instruct the buildsystem to compile the `systray.rc` file using the [resource compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resource-compiler) to produce a `systray.res` file which will be linked to the systray.exe program.

here is an example `systray.rc` file:

```
LANGUAGE 9, 1
1 VERSIONINFO
  FILEVERSION    1, 0, 0, 0
  PRODUCTVERSION 1, 0, 0, 0
  FILEOS         4
  FILETYPE       1
{
  BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
  {
    BLOCK "040904E4"
    {
      VALUE "CompanyName", "Contoso"
      VALUE "FileDescription", "SysTray demo program"
      VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
      VALUE "InternalName", "systray"
      VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright \251 2020 Your Name"
      VALUE "OriginalFilename", "systray.exe"
      VALUE "ProductName", "SysTray Demo"
      VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0"
    }
  }
  BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
  {
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409, 1252
  }
}

LANGUAGE 10, 3
1 VERSIONINFO
  FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
  PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
  FILEOS 0x04
  FILETYPE 0x1
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "0C0A04E4"
        {
                VALUE "CompanyName", "Contoso"
                VALUE "FileDescription", "Programa demostrativo SysTray"
                VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
                VALUE "InternalName", "systray"
                VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright \xA9 2020 Tu Nombre"
                VALUE "OriginalFilename", "systray.exe"
                VALUE "ProductName", "Demo SysTray"
                VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0"
        }
    }
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
            VALUE "Translation", 0x0C0A 0x04E4
    }
}
```

This example contains two [VERSIONINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource) block resources, one in English and another in Spanish. The executable `systray.exe` will have both resources embedded. Windows will choose one of them to present the users with the program properties in Windows Explorer, and when showing the toast notifications the `FileDescription` value will become your footer. You can't remove it, but you can give it any value you want for each language.

Windows determines which resource to display automatically depending on Windows configuration. It may be a good idea to include one block for `LANG_NEUTRAL` (0, neutral language). See the [language identifier constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings).